# Usar fechas concatenadas para consulta sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Que tal lo que intento es generar una lista con las ventas de este año y del año pasado, conforme a las fechas que ingrese el usuario

Solo que tengo un problema al querer concatenar los datos para que pase los valores como '2020-06-11 23:59:59.000'

Pero me mandar los valores en null ya que no los pasa a la consulta

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Qtzsp_VentasGraficadas] 
    @FechaIni datetime,
    @FechaFin datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Dia datetime
    DECLARE @Hora time
    DECLARE @DiaAnt datetime
    DECLARE @FechaIniAnt datetime
    DECLARE @VentasAnioActual money
    DECLARE @DiaFin datetime

    SET @Hora = (SELECT CAST('11:59PM' AS TIME))
    SET @Dia = CONVERT(datetime,@FechaIni,21)
    SET @DiaAnt = DATEADD(YYYY,-1,CONVERT(datetime,@FechaIni,21))

    CREATE TABLE #TablaTemporal (Fecha datetime)

    WHILE(@Dia < CONVERT(datetime,@FechaFin,21))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TablaTemporal
        SELECT 
        @Dia

        SET @DiaFin = CONCAT_WS(' ',CONVERT(CHAR(8),@Dia,101),CONVERT(CHAR(8),@Hora,108))

        SET @VentasAnioActual = (SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) FROM CATALOGO_CORTE WHERE FECHA_HORA BETWEEN @Dia 
        AND CONVERT(varchar(24), CONVERT(DATETIME,@DiaFin,103),121))

        INSERT INTO TemporalGraficaVentas (VentasAnio2020,FechasDeVenta) VALUES (@VentasAnioActual,@Dia)

    SET @Dia = DATEADD(DD,1,@Dia)
    END
  END
```

Cuando ejecuto `CONVERT(varchar(24), CONVERT(DATETIME,@DiaFin,103),121))` si me manda los valores como quiero pero al pasarlo a la consulta no lo detecta como dato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno ya lo pude resolver y dejo el codigo por si alguno le sirve

lo que hice fue agregar las horas a la fecha que ya tenia y asi no tuve que concatenar
Este reporte es para obtener las ventas de un año anterior y el actual

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Qtzsp_VentasGraficadas] 
    @FechaIni datetime,
    @FechaFin datetime,
    @Sucursal varchar(8)
AS
BEGIN

    TRUNCATE TABLE TemporalGraficaVentas

    DECLARE @Dia datetime
    DECLARE @Hora time
    DECLARE @DiaAnt datetime
    DECLARE @FechaIniAnt datetime
    DECLARE @VentasAnioActual money
    DECLARE @VentasAnioAnt money
    DECLARE @DiaFin datetime

    SET @Hora = (SELECT CAST('11:59PM' AS TIME))
    SET @Dia = CONVERT(datetime,@FechaIni,21)
    SET @DiaAnt = DATEADD(YYYY,-1,CONVERT(datetime,@FechaIni,21))

    CREATE TABLE #TablaTemporal (Fecha datetime, Fecha2 datetime)

    WHILE(@Dia < CONVERT(datetime,@FechaFin,21))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TablaTemporal (Fecha) SELECT @Dia 

        UPDATE #TablaTemporal SET Fecha2 = (SELECT DATEADD(HH,23,@Dia)) WHERE Fecha = @Dia 

        SET @VentasAnioActual = (ISNULL((SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) FROM CATALOGO_CORTE WHERE FECHA_HORA BETWEEN 
        (SELECT Fecha FROM #TablaTemporal WHERE Fecha = @Dia) AND 
        (SELECT Fecha2 FROM #TablaTemporal WHERE Fecha = @Dia) AND CodigoSucursal = @Sucursal),0))

        INSERT INTO TemporalGraficaVentas (VentasAnio2020,FechasDeVenta) VALUES (@VentasAnioActual,@Dia)

    SET @Dia = DATEADD(DD,1,@Dia)

    END

    CREATE TABLE #TablaTemporal2 (Fecha datetime, Fecha2 datetime)

    WHILE(@DiaAnt < DATEADD(YYYY,-1,CONVERT(datetime,@FechaFin,21)))
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO #TablaTemporal2 (Fecha) SELECT @DiaAnt

      UPDATE #TablaTemporal2 SET Fecha2 = (SELECT DATEADD(HH,23,@DiaAnt)) WHERE Fecha = @DiaAnt 

      SET @VentasAnioAnt = (ISNULL((SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) FROM CATALOGO_CORTE WHERE FECHA_HORA BETWEEN 
        (SELECT Fecha FROM #TablaTemporal2 WHERE Fecha = @DiaAnt) AND 
        (SELECT Fecha2 FROM #TablaTemporal2 WHERE Fecha = @DiaAnt) AND CodigoSucursal = @Sucursal),0))

        UPDATE TemporalGraficaVentas SET VentasAnio2019 = @VentasAnioAnt, FechaDeVentaAnt = @DiaAnt WHERE FechasDeVenta = DATEADD(YYYY,+1,@DiaAnt)

      SET @DiaAnt = DATEADD(DD,1,@DiaAnt)

    END
    SELECT * FROM TemporalGraficaVentas

END
```